# For loop stops after 1st case

Tags: python

I have a for loop that goes through each word in a string and returns a modified string.

However, the loop stops after the first word.

The summarized code looks like this:

```
def format(x):
    return x
def modify(string):
    for x in words:
        if statement:
            return x[v:] + x[:v] + "xx"
        else:
            return x + "xx"
def final(string):
    return format(modify(string))
```

The format function format what modify does, while the final function puts everything together. It works perfect for the first word in the string, but stops after that.

Current input and output:

```
>>>final("This is a test case")
>>>>Htisxx
```

What I want:

```
>>>final("This is a test case")
>>>>Htisxx isxx axx esttxx asecxx
```

Why does the loop stop? How can I fix this?

Comment: Hard to say for sure with 'summarized code' but it looks like maybe you're looking for the [yield statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement).

Comment: for/else is an allowed construct in python, but it is redundant (you can remove the else and deindent and it does the same thing) and is not good for code clarity.  See discussion in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006155.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` immediately leaves the function, even if you are only on the first pass through your `for` loop.

Instead, try

```
def first_vowel(word):
    for offset,ch in enumerate(word):
        if ch in "aeiou":
            return offset
    return 0

def modify_word(word):
    v = first_vowel(word)
    return word[v:] + word[:v] + "xx"

def modify(s):
    words = s.split()
    return ' '.join(modify_word(word) for word in words)

def format(s):
    return s

def final(s):
    return format(modify(s))

final("This is a test case")  # => 'isThxx isxx axx esttxx asecxx'
```

Comment: So is there anyway around this or am I forced to use print?

Answer (score -1):

Increase the indention of the else block as following:

```
def format(x):
    return x
def modify(string):
    for x in words:
        if statement:
            return x[v:] + x[:v] + "xx"
        else:
            return x + "xx"
def final(string):
    return format(modify(string))
```

Comment: Im sorry, that was a mistake I made while writing the question. My indentations are correct.